# how to enter a random value in a textarea without an id?

Tags: javascript, textarea, greasemonkey

I have to enter a random value in a `textarea` of a web site by using grease monkey script the text area didn't have an `id` so `document.getElementById` doesn't work.

Can I use another method to do that?

My current HTML showing my `textarea`:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdv pd5"><span class="tbg">
        Message</span>&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="pd5">
        <textarea name="inpx_msg" class="msgbox"></textarea>
        <br />
        <div class="tsm">140 characters max.</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**element.querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector) if you want to be able to specifically target an element using a CSS selector, similar to this:

```
var textArea = document.querySelector('table tr td.pd5 textarea.msgbox');
textArea.value = "My Random Text";
```

The above is working on the following HTML example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdv pd5"><span class="tbg">Message</span>&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td class="pd5">
                <textarea name="inpx_msg" class="msgbox"></textarea>
                <br />
                <div class="tsm">140 characters max.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFJeM/) - Using `element.querySelector`

---

Off course, you can now change the CSS selector to anything you like to match your DOM hierarchy. There is lots of flexibility using `element.querySelector`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName):

```
document.getElementsByName("inpx_msg")[0]
```

Obviously, you'll have to check if it exists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]
```

Of course, if you have more than one textarea tag, you will have to distinguish between them based on properties they might have. Or, if you know your textarea resides inside a specific element which has an ID, you could try

```
document.getElementById("someparentid").getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]
```